# Mathematically, why aren't the creation and annihilation operators Hermitian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

Take for instance the one-dimensional creation operator $\hat a$:
$$\begin{equation}
    \hat a = \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hslash}}\left(\hat x + i \frac{\hat{p}_x}{m\omega}\right) \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}$$
An operator $\hat O$ is self-adjoint if $\hat O = \hat O^\dagger$; applying this to $\hat{a}$,
$$\begin{align}
    \hat{a}^\dagger &= \left[ \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hslash}}\left(\hat x + i \frac{\hat{p}_x}{m\omega}\right) \right]^\dagger \tag{2}\label{2}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hslash}}\left(\hat x^\star - i \frac{\hat{p}_x^\star}{m\omega}\right) \tag{3}\label{3}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hslash}} \left(x - i\frac{(-i\hslash\partial_x)^\star}{m\omega}\right) \tag{4}\label{4}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hslash}} \left(x + \frac{\hslash\partial_x}{m\omega}\right) \tag{5}\label{5}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hslash}}\left(\hat x + i \frac{(-i\hslash\partial_x)}{m\omega}\right) \tag{6}\label{6} \\
&= \hat{a} \tag{7}\label{7}
\end{align}$$
needless to say that this process has been done in *position space*. Anyway, as you can see, $\hat{a}=\hat{a}^\dagger$; yet, the creation operator $\hat{a}$ is factually *not* Hermitian.

In fact, $\hat a^\dagger$ and $\hat a$ cannot be equal otherwise the creation and annihilation operators woould the same thing and that wouldn't make sense... So I don't see what I did wrong when calculating $\hat a^\dagger$ above. According to my professor, my math is correct (he barely looked at it tbh), the reason why $\hat a$ is not Hermitian is because:

> The expression for $\hat a$ is $ \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hslash}}\left(\hat x + i \frac{\hat{p}_x}{m\omega}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hslash}} \left(x + \frac{\hslash}{m\omega}\frac{d}{dx}\right)$. It has a $\tfrac{d}{dx}$ which is not Hermitian, so $\hat a$ is not Hermitian.

I get that $d/dx$ is not Hermitian, but I'm still confused since I've shown that $\hat{a}=\hat{a}^\dagger$. My professor's statement did get me thinking however... **Is $\hat a$ not Hermitian because to show that it is Hermitian I must show that its adjoint is the same as itself in Hilbert space, but instead I've shown this in position space?**

Any help would be much appretiated.

Comment: The manipulations (2)-(7) are not correct.

Comment: Maybe it is because I didn't consider $\partial_x^\dagger$, which is $-\partial_x$. I think this would make sense @Qmechanic

Comment: Yes. The operator $\partial_x$ is anti-Hermitian.

Comment: Note that $\dagger$ is the same as complex conjugation ONLY when acting on numbers. So you CANNOT say that $\partial_x^\dagger = \partial_x^* = \partial_x$ since $\partial_x$ is an operator that acts on the wave-function. Instead, we have $\partial_x^\dagger = - \partial_x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\hat p_x^\dagger = p_x$. This can be shown by the following calculation.

\begin{align}
\langle \psi_1, \hat p_x \psi_2 \rangle &= \int dx \, \psi_1^* (-i \partial_x \psi_2) \\
&= \int dx \, (i\partial_x \psi_1^*  ) \psi_2 \\
&= \int dx \, (- i\partial_x \psi_1  )^* \psi_2 \\
&= \langle \hat p_x \psi_1, \psi_2 \rangle
\end{align}
In the second step we integrated by parts, shifting the derivative from $\psi_2$ to $\psi_1$ and introducing a relative minus sign. However, when we bring the operator inside of the $(...)^*$, the $i$ introduces another minus sign. The full result is to simply shift $\hat p_x$ from $\psi_1$ to $\psi_2$. In general, for any operator $\hat A$ the adjoint $\hat A^\dagger$ is defined by
$$
\langle \psi_1, \hat A \psi_2 \rangle = \langle \hat A^\dagger \psi_1, \psi_2 \rangle
$$
which implies that $\hat p_x^\dagger = \hat p_x$.

Comment: I see. I made a mistake in my calculation as I forgot to consider the adjoint of $d/dx$!